# Request Connection refused in two web apps in a server

Tags: java, http, request, httpclient

I deploy two web apps in the same  jetty in a server, `AppA` and `AppB`.

AnyOne in the WWW can access the two apps by the Domain  mapped to the IP address of the server `www.name.com/appA` and `www.name.com/appB`. 
The port of jetty is 8080.

The reason why we can access the app by www.name.com.appA in the port 80 is that I have mapped the outer Internet port 80 to the port 8080 in the inner server.

I need to access the data of the appA in the appB, just in a HTTP request like `www.name.com/appA/requestXXX`, but it fails with

> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to name.com:80
>   [name.com/xx.xx.xxx.xxx] failed: Connection refused.

Comment: It sounds like a configuration problem. Maybe it's not routing requests that come from the server itself. If you can, you could always connect to port `8080` directly, although that would require that your apps are always deployed together.

Comment: yeah,it's a solution.But it will fail  if i deploy the apps seperately. It gives me some inspiration, Thank you very much.I know little about the net configuration.I will find another way.